# Format a new Date() to E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a date/time displayed using "new date()".

It currently displays

```
Thu May 17 2018 18:52:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I need this?

```
Thu May 17 2018 18:43:42 GMTIST
```

Comment: you can check date pipe here [link](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Answer (score 0):

you can use pipe or date filter 
so here you just have to specify the way you want to display your date 
    {{Po.sysCreatedDate |date:'MMM dd,yyyy' }}

```
{{datetime|date:'EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}
```

this not the formate you demand but using this code you can formate your date

use this link 
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_date.asp

Comment: i don't want to use date pipe is there any way to do this,help me

Comment: you can use new Date() method in your .ts